# JDBC MySQL; is supplying the DB name & username/password enough?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, jdbc

When setting up a JDBC connection in a J2EE application, do you need to specify the schema name in addition to the database name?

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-create-drop-database.aspx) and have setup a database, and username/password, but I'm coming up against this error when I startup my application. Is it possible that DBUnit is trying to insert the data, before hibernate has initiated and created the schema?

```
Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: Did not find table 'CLIENT' in schema 'null'
```

My connection details are as follows :

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/salestracker"/>
        <property name="username" value="salestracker"/>
        <property name="password" value="salestracker"/>
    </bean>
```

I have created the database :

```
[james@nevada sales-tracker]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 16
Server version: 5.1.42 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| salestracker       |
| test               |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Do I need to specify something in my hibernate persistence.xml that says to "use" a particular database? I was assuming this would be implied in the JDBC URL

Comment: Inside of your `salestracker` database do you have a `CLIENT` table?

Comment: the database is empty, I have this in hibernate which I believe should create the database structure for me : `<!--Automatically create the SQL schema -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>`

Comment: sometimes hibernate has problems generating the schema, which it aptly reports in the logs. Check if the table is there and then check the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the database as root and run 'desc client' to see if the table is there (or 'show tables').  If it doesn't find it, then Hibernate isn't auto-creating it. If it does find it, try connecting as salestracker and doing the same thing to see if maybe that user doesn't have the correct permissions.  If the table is really there, the next step would be to write a simple Java program to connect and query the table, i.e. remove Hibernate from the equation.  Something like:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/salestracker", "salestracker", "salestracker"); 
PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) from client"); 
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(); 
rs.next(); 
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
```